# Split data based on column values and create scatter plot.

Tags: r

I need to make a scatter plot for `days vs age` for the f group (sex=1) and make another scatter plot for `days vs age` for the m group (sex=2) using R.

```
days  age sex
 306  74   1
 455  67   2
1000  55   1
 505  65   1
 399  54   2
 495  66   2
 ...
```

How do I extract the data by sex? I know after that to use `plot()` function to create a scatter plot.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with the traditional R graphics functions like:

```
plot(age ~ days, Data[Data$sex == 1, ])
plot(age ~ days, Data[Data$sex == 2, ])
```

If you prefer to color the points rather than separate the plots (which might be easier to understand) you can do:

```
plot(age ~ days, Data, col=Data$sex)
```

However, this kind of plot would be especially easy (and better looking) using [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org/):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Data, aes(x=days, y=age)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~sex)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`spread`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.7.0/topics/spread) splits data by column values. This is also called [converting data from "long" to "wide"](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/).

I haven't tested this, but something like

```
spread(data, sex, age)
```

should get you

```
days  1    2
 306  74   NA
 455  NA   67   
1000  55   NA
 505  65   NA
 399  NA   54   
 495  NA   66
```