# Creating plots, after applying functions on splitted data in R

Tags: r, plot, split

thanks in advance for your time on reading and answering this.
I have a data frame (15264*3) the head of which is:

```
head(actData)
      steps  date      interval
289     0 2012-10-02        0
290     0 2012-10-02        5
291     0 2012-10-02       10
292     0 2012-10-02       15
293     0 2012-10-02       20
294     0 2012-10-02       25
```

There are 53 of the "date" variable (factor); I want to split the data based on date, calculate the mean of the steps/date and then create a plot for interval vs. steps' mean;
What I have done:

```
mn<- ddply(actData, c("date"), function (x) apply(x[1], 2, mean)) # to calculate mean of steps per day (with the length of 53)
splt<- split(actData, actData$date) # split the data based on date (it should divide the data into 53 parts)
```

Now I have two variables with the same length (53); but when I try plotting them, I get an error for the difference in their length:

```
plot(splt$interval, mn[,2], type="l")  
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

when I check the length of splt$interval, it gives me "0"!
I've also visited here "[How to split a data frame by rows, and then process the blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395191/how-to-split-a-data-frame-by-rows-and-then-process-the-blocks)", "[Split data based on column values and create scatter plot.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592742/split-data-based-on-column-values-and-create-scatter-plot)" and so on... with a lot of good suggestions but none of them addresses my questions!
Sorry if my question is a little stupid, I am not an expert in R :)

I am using windows 7, Rstudio 3.0.1.
Thanks.

EDIT:

```
head(splt, 2)
$`2012-10-01`
[1] steps    date     interval
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`2012-10-02`
     steps   date     interval
289     0 2012-10-02        0
290     0 2012-10-02        5
291     0 2012-10-02       10
292     0 2012-10-02       15 

head(mn)
    date    steps
1 2012-10-02  0.43750
2 2012-10-03 39.41667
3 2012-10-04 42.06944
4 2012-10-05 46.15972
5 2012-10-06 53.54167
6 2012-10-07 38.24653
```

Comment: It could be something to do with `levels` but could you print the head of splt and mn or better (IMO) their `dput`?

Comment: `splt$interval` is NULL, because `splt` is a list that contains data frames, so you'd have to do something like `splt[[1]]$interval` to get the intervals.  That said, do you want to plot the mean steps vs. the mean interval?  Or for every interval in a given day, that value against the mean of steps for that day?  It seems like you need to summarize `interval` as well as `steps`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to split the data based on date, calculate the mean of the steps/date and then create a plot for interval vs. steps' mean;

After step 2, you will have a matrix like this:

```
      mean(steps)  date     
289     0.23     2012-10-02
290     0.42     2012-10-03
291     0.31     2012-10-04
```

You want to plot this against *"the intervals"*, but there are also multiple intervals per 'date'. What are you exactly trying to plot in x vs y?

- The mean steps per date?
- The mean steps vs mean intervals (i.e. an x-y point per date)?

Comment: I am asked to make a plot of the 5-minute interval (x-axis) and the average number of steps taken, averaged across all days (y-axis)... obviously, I cannot make a plot of mean steps vs. the whole intervals because of the length difference, so making plot of the mean steps vs. intervals which are splited baed on date is reasonable!

Comment: Actually I have to create a time series plot of them, so maybe this code addresses my question: xyplot(actData$steps~ actData$interval | actData$date, type= "l"). right? but it still does not consider the funcion mean for steps!!